# V8's equivalence of SpiderMonkey's catch(e if e..)

Tags: javascript, exception, v8, spidermonkey

Using SpiderMonkey you can utilize conditional catch blocks to route exceptions to the appropriate handler.

```
try {
// function could throw three exceptions
getCustInfo("Lee", 1234, "lee@netscape.com")
}
catch (e if e == "InvalidNameException") {
// call handler for invalid names
bad_name_handler(e)
}
catch (e if e == "InvalidIdException") {
// call handler for invalid ids
bad_id_handler(e)
}
catch (e if e == "InvalidEmailException") {
// call handler for invalid email addresses
bad_email_handler(e)
}
catch (e){
// don't know what to do, but log it
logError(e)
}
```

*example from MDN*

However in V8 this code wont compile, any suggestions, or work arounds other than the obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no similar feature in the other JavaScript engines as far as I know.

But it is easy to convert code using this feature:

```
try {
    A
} catch (e if B) {
    C
}
```

into code that just uses standard features that all the JavaScript engines support:

```
try {
    A
} catch (e) {
    if (B) {
        C
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The example you gave is even easier to translate:

```
try {
    getCustInfo("Lee", 1234, "lee@netscape.com");
} catch (e) {
    if (e == "InvalidNameException") {
        bad_name_handler(e);
    } else if (e == "InvalidIdException") {
        bad_id_handler(e);
    } else if (e == "InvalidEmailException") {
        bad_email_handler(e);
    } else {
        logError(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that the obvious thing, a switch statement maybe even better, your sure there is no similar implementations?

Comment: Yes. It's a nonstandard extension in SpiderMonkey.

Comment: Side Note: this does not handle things like stack traces if you want to not catch an exception of a certain type.